# How should unit testing be done for gestures in iOS?

Tags: ios, unit-testing

I am confused how unit testing for gestures should be done in iOS. In my application, panning a scrollview triggers an event handler that then does some stuff. When unit testing this am I supposed to:

1. Call the event handler directly and check to see if it does what its supposed to
2. Simulate the panning with some UI automation testing framework, check to see if the event handler is called, and then finally see if its the desired outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not call the eventhandler directly but instead use test frameworks doing the gestures for you.

The Apple Framework is [UIAutomation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/_index.html) - you can code your UITests via `javascript` just with instruments and even test your code immediately. Unfortunately it doesn't integrate well with `hudson / jenkins` because command line support is not really good.

What I am using in one of my projects is [KIF](https://github.com/square/KIF) - it works very well on you `CI Server` and you can code your Tests with `xcode` and `objective-c`